# Syntax error resulting from invalid syntax in if / else statements

Tags: javascript

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!

confirm("Are you ready to play?");

var age = prompt("What's your age");

if ( age is less than 13)
{
    console.log("You are allowed to play,but we take no responsibility");
}

else {
console.log("Go on! you can play");
}
```

I've got a syntax error while executing this JavaScript code, the first two lines (confirm and variable) are correct, this error is somewhere in the if / else satements.

Comment: The first line is "correct" in the sense of being syntactically valid, but it is incorrect in the sense that there is no point using confirm() if you don't test the result to see which button the user pressed. Also the messages in the console.log() statements seem to be intended for the user, but they won't see them in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<` operator instead of `is less than`

```js
// Check if the user is ready to play!

confirm("Are you ready to play?");

var age = prompt("What's your age");
if (age < 13) {
  alert("You are allowed to play, but we take no responsibility");
} else {
  alert("Go on! you can play");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce line of code also by using ternary operator

```
 age < 13 ?  console.log("You are allowed to play, but we take no      responsibility"):console.log("Go on! you can play");
```

Comment: You can reduce it further by putting the ternary operator inside a single console.log().